# How can I find what Lua API functions are supported in my Neovim?

Tags: neovim, lua

When I try to run the following code in my conf or under `:luado`

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({"BufNewFile", "BufRead"}, {
  pattern  = {"*.t"},
  callback = function () vim.bo.filetype = 'perl' end
})
```

I get the following error,

```
attempt to call field 'nvim_create_autocmd' (a nil value)
```

[I can see `nvim_create_autocmd` documented here](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#nvim_create_autocmd()); I am assuming this error is because my version of Neovim doesn't support this api function. I can re-create this error with `:luado`,

```
:luado vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({"BufNewFile", "BufRead"}, { pattern  = {"*.t" }, callback = function () vim.bo.filetype = 'perl' end })
```

How can I see what functions my Neovim supports?

Comment: Could it be a version difference? Always try your local `:help` first to make sure it matches your system

Comment: `:echo api_info().functions->map("v:val.name")->filter("v:val=~'^nvim_create'")`

Comment: @Matt that is really cool, if you answer with just that I'll fix it up and mark it as chosen. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

You can see what is supported through the Lua API with the metadata provided by [`vim.fn.api_info`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#api-metadata), but it won't be very useful nor readable. It returns a [dictionary](https://neovim.io/doc/user/eval.html#Dictionary). From the docs to `api_info()`, you can make it readble by wrapping it in `:lua print(vim.inspect( thing ))`, like this

```
:lua print(vim.inspect( vim.fn.api_info() ))
```

You're only interested in the functions supported not the error types and other stuff, so you can use

```
:lua print(vim.inspect( vim.fn.api_info().functions ))
```

---

Another method to do this is with [`api_info()`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/builtin.html#api_info()), and provided by [@Matt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/22797/matt). Here he maps over it to get just the function names, and then filters to find only the names that are prefixed with `nvim_create`.

```
:echo api_info().functions->map("v:val.name")->filter("v:val=~'^nvim_create'")
```